# Is it OK to guide those asking off topic questions to other sites?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Salaam alaikum

I saw [this post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/64983/how-to-preach-non-muslim-friends-using-al-quran), where a mod commented saying that the post was off topic. They're are other sites for p which the question is on topic, and he would likely receive valuable input, إن شاء الله. Is it allowed to refer people to other sites like this in this case?

Comment: First of all a question closure is not the end of the world because the author or a different user could edit it and make it suitable for this site. Then a re-open review queue will be launched in which users will decide whether this question shall be re-opened or not. Please check the [help] and read the topics. Whether a person asks a question here or elsewhere is far away of being in our responsibility or authority nor do we know how other sites will act upon it. We are a question and answer site not a typical internet forum. Only "**answerable**" questions should be posted here.